# How to get a value from an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Having an array of objects, how can i get the quiz value from the array of objects printed below? `( [quiz] => 5223)`

```
Array (
    [128593] => stdClass Object  (
            [id] => 128593
            [uniqueid] => 130738
            [quiz] => 5223
            [userid] => 2
            [attempt] => 1
            [timestart] => 1382638443
            [timefinish] => 0
            [timemodified] => 1382638443
        )
)
```

Comment: lol @ three exact same answers within 30 secs ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy actually:

```
$quiz = $array[128593]->quiz;
```

**EDIT** some background:

An array is, simply said, a list in which you can access it's values by using the key. Let's say you have the following array:

```
$names[1] = 'Berry';
$names[8] = 'John';
echo $names[1]; // this line outputs Berry
```

The key of the first element (holding the name 'Berry') is the number 1, the key of the second one would be 8.

The value of an array can actually be everything; a boolean, integer, string, object, and even another array. So all below is correct:

```
$array[1] = 1; // an integer
$array[2] = true; // a boolean
$array[3] = new stdClass; // an object of class stdClass
$array[4] = array(1 => 'the first value');
```

You already know how to access an array value. now look at example 4 (array within an array). To access it's element you'd use:

```
echo $array[4][1]; // outputs "the first value"
```

which is equivalent to

```
$my_element = $array[4];
echo $my_element[1];
```

Back to your case: you first need to access the array element holding your quiz information, like this:

```
$quiz_element = $array[128593];
```

And then get the 'quiz' property of the object:

```
echo $quiz_element->quiz;
```

And in short that would be:

```
echo $array[128593]->quiz;
```

So yes it's pretty much correct: to access a certain array element you need to pass it's key (which you called id), and to get a property of an object can just give the property name.

Comment: thank's a lot! is this correct to say that you need to pass the id of the array and so the property name to get the property value ?

Comment: Thank's i have a much better understanding of arrays using php now. Cristal clear !!

Answer (score 6):

```
echo $array[128593]->quiz;
```

Inside the array you have an object so you need to access its properties using `->`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo($array[128593]->quiz);
```

Comment: Why post same answers rather than upvote existing one? :\

Comment: I we have posted at hte same time or some second after.. if you see @AlmaDoMundo

Comment: probably because we were all writing our answer at the same time ;)

Comment: just like these two comments :D

Answer (score 1):

If the array is always one element with an unknown id (I called the array $result)

```
$obj = array_pop($result);
echo($obj->quiz);
```